# For CSS added with vhs.asset config.compressCss does not work

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I try to compress my CSS and JS files, for that I set the compressionLevel in the Installtool to 9 for BE and FE. and I added following Typoscript to my setup.txt in my template:

```
config.compressCss = 1
config.compressJs = 1
config.concatenateCss = 1
config.concatenateJs = 1

plugin.tx_vhs.settings.asset {
    fonts1 {
        type = css
        name = font1
        path = https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Istok+Web:400,700
        standalone =  1
        external = 1
    }
    styles {
        type= css
        name = main-style
        path = EXT:my_template/Resources/Public/css/main.css
        standalone =  1
    }
}
```

Now some CSS files from extensions get compressed, but the one I add via vhs.asset does not get compressed at all.

Any idea why the compression does not work with the CSS (and JS) added via vhs.asset?

Answer (score 1):

Although such an option exists in TYPO3 CMS, it is not a CMS job, but rather server's job (Apache, nginx, etc.).

So, if you have an nginx server, it can be done with following configuration (and, probably, it is already turned on in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`):

```
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/xml text/css text/javascript application/json  application/xml application/xml+rss application/x-javascript;
```

For Apache you need a `mod_deflate` and following lines in your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript 
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml+rss
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Benefits:

- separation of responsibilities: server serves the assets, while CMS provides them;
- more types can be compressed, not just CSS and JS;
- no matter how the assets are served - TS, VHS, just linked via `link` or `style` tags - they will be always compressed;

Size of compressed data will be same in both cases (sure, depends also on compression level set), because same libraries and algorithms are used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to include your css / js :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#   Distribution Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts
#-------------------------------------------------
page = PAGE
page {
    # CSS files to be included
    includeCSS {
        myTemplate = EXT:my_template/Resources/Public/Css/main.css
    }
    # JS to be included (mind how other JS is included)
    # includeJSFooter is also very common
    includeJS {
        myTemplate = EXT:my_template/Resources/Public/JavaScript/script.js
    }
}
```

(ps: you do have to include your static template in this case)

Comment: Thanks. But I use vhs.asset also on plugins and would really like to keep it

Comment: I don't get your answer ... you do not have to renounce on vhs.asset, just use this to bind in your css and js ... the plugin would not use these in any other way ...

Comment: vhs.asset creates a file like typo3temp/vhs-assets-main-script.js?1476289183` and then adds them into the html output. I tested the typoscript and it did not change anything. Maybe I do not understand how this should work?

Comment: [docs.typo3](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#compresscss) here it states clearly that compression will be applied to CSS referenced in page.includeCSS, this then gets 'worked' by typo3 and stored in typo3temp for use ...

Comment: @webman, *nbar* uses [VHS Assets](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Asset/StyleViewHelper.html) extension, which has nothing to do with `page.includeCSS`, so compression needs to be enabled different way.